# Unable to import dump file into oracle by SQL Developer in windows

Tags: windows, oracle, directory, oracle-sqldeveloper, dump

I encountered the ORA-31640 exception, unable to open dump file "C:\DATA_DUMP_DIR/20191103.DMP" for read. I think it's about the backslash issue which is on windows. Could you give some suggestion to solve this?
And I have created directory in the oracle.
Could you give some suggestions? thanks

[image]

Comment: Is sqldev running on the same host as the DB? Is the file on the db server or your PC (if they are not the same)?

Comment: Hi @gsalem, Actually, I don't think so, as sqldev is running on my physical PC, oracle is running on the local docker container.

Comment: The file must be in a directory seen by the server, so in your docker instance, not your PC under Windows.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is actually there and that the oracle OS user has read/write privileges on it. Also, please check filename's spelling.